# Sorting (album) artist in iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, music, album

I was wondering how to list an album as another artist's work in iTunes "Artists" view.

I have an album whose artist and album artist are "eason and the duo band". I would like to list the album as "Eason Chan" by using the "Sorting" feature. However, the album still belongs to "eason and the duo band" in "Artists" view.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Just to clarify, are you saying that the albums are sorting fine, but you just want the Artist to appear as *Eason Chan* instead of *eason and the duo band*? Or, are you saying that it's not sorting properly?

Comment: Yes, I want the artist to appear as _Eason Chan_ instead of _Eason and the duo band_ without changing the artist or album artist. Is it possible? I thought Sorting feature is designed for this purpose. Maybe I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Artist` and `Album Artist` fields display whatever is recorded in the metadata. In this case, both of these fields contain *eason and the duo band*.

The only way to change what is displayed is to actually change what is recorded. Your screenshot shows that you already know how to access the metadata (i.e. using the Get Info/Song Info option or pressing <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>) to bring up the details.

You would need to do that and actually change the information stored there. To do this, make sure you're on the **Details** tab and edit the info in `Artist` and/or `Album Artist`. Once you've clicked <kbd>OK</kbd> to save the data, you'll find what is displayed for these songs/albums will also change.

As for the `Sort As` field, this dictates which field iTunes will use to sort the information, not what is actually displayed in the fields.